# Nodejs d3 package gives error

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I am getting below error while trying to use d3 package on node.js.

```
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000775,
       "message": "\n/var/task/node_modules/d3/d3.js:562\n"
   },
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000775,
       "message": "    return n.querySelector(s);\n"
   },
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000775,
       "message": "             ^\n"
   },
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000835,
       "message": "TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of undefined\n"
   },
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000835,
       "message": "    at d3_select (/var/task/node_modules/d3/d3.js:562:14)\n"
   },
   {
       "ingestionTime": 1435227001159,
       "timestamp": 1435227000835,
       "message": "    at Object.d3.select (/var/task/node_modules/d3/d3.js:1043:17)\n"
   },
```

I have used both 3.5.3 and latest 3.5.5 but both give same error.

And my node.js code is:

```
var d3 = require("d3");
var d3MeasureText = require('d3-measure-text');
d3MeasureText.d3 = d3;

var dim = d3MeasureText("Time (days)");
console.dir(dim);
```

Can you please help me, what I am doing wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: I have already mentioned the error on the question.

Comment: Are including the d3 library in your code. I see that you require it but you would get this error if d3 is not declared or missing.